# Century Gothic Font in Linux

Tags: python, html, css, django, fonts

So I created a website on mac using Django, Python, HTML and CSS, which uses quite a lot of Century Gothic font. However the website will be run on Linux and since Linux does not have the font Century Gothic, it looks really bad. I need a way to make the Century Gothic font work on Linux.

Answer (score 6):

You have two ways to do that:

1. Upload a "ttf" and a "eot" (for IE9) file of `Century Gothic Font` in your server and write in your main `CSS` something like:

   ```
   @font-face {
       font-family: myFirstFont;
       src: url('URL/CenturyGothic.ttf'),
            url('URL/CenturyGothic.eot'); /* IE9 */
   }
   ```
2. You can use a Century Gothic alternative (like [Didact Gothic](http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Didact+Gothic)) from `Google Web fonts`, so, in `<head>` tags put this code:

   ```
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Didact+Gothic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   ```

   And, in your `CSS`:

   ```
   font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
   ```

Comment: So can the 'URL' be something like '/User/Name/project/CenturyGothic.ttf'

Comment: You might prefer though to choose a font which does not require you to pay a license fee to use it on your website.

Answer (score 0):

Embed the font in the css using
    @font-face
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Comment: So where should I keep my Century Gothik ttf file in order for this to work ? Is it in templates ?